# Unclear function return type issue

Tags: f#, type-inference

I have the following rather simple F# function:

```ml
let FormatValue (formatProvider : IFormatProvider) valueSuffix value =
    match value > Convert.ToDecimal(valueSuffix.MinimumValueRequired) with
    | true -> let normalizedValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value) / Convert.ToDecimal((Math.Pow(10., Convert.ToDouble(valueSuffix.PowerOfTen)))) in
                  string.Format("{0}{1}", normalizedValue.ToString(valueSuffix.Format, formatProvider), valueSuffix.Text)
    | false -> ""
```

The return type is correctly inferred as `string`, however I get an error marker at `string.Format` in the `true` branch, saying the type `<'a> -> string` is not compatible with type `ValueSuffix`. I find this especially surprising as all other types are inferred correctly, and in particular there is no other occurrence of `<'a>` in the function.

What am I doing and/or understanding wrong?

Comment: I don't think `string.Format` is ever valid in F#.  It should be `System.String.Format` or `String.Format` with an `open System` earlier.  Also, you should mention you are using verbose syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that did it; I needed to use the class instead of the type. Can you add that as an answer, so I can accept it? (Oh, and I'm not really using verbose syntax; the `in` just slipped in while I was trying to get it to work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that `string.Format` is not valid in F# code.

You need to either use

```
System.String.Format
```

or

```
open System
.....
String.Format
```

(The difference is upper versus lower case `s` in `string`

Answer (score 3):

John Palmer's answer is correct, but I've often wondered why `string.Format` is *not* valid in F# code, and until this question I had not bothered to investigate it.

Looking at the [relevant source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/19507b98bc6a7995e9c19c40f044fdfeb578ef77/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types-prelude.fs), we see that `string` is just a type alias for `System.String`. So it seems like we *should* be able to use it just like `System.String`. For example, suppose we define the following type alias:

`type foo = System.String`

This will allow us to do things like `foo.Format` without issue.

The problem is that not only is `string` defined as a type alias, it is [also defined](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/19507b98bc6a7995e9c19c40f044fdfeb578ef77/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L4174) as conversion function. This effectively shadows the type alias except in contexts where only a type name could be expected (e.g. type annotations and casts).

We can demonstrate this by defining our own conversion function to shadow our `foo` type alias:

```
let foo value = 
    match box value with
    | null -> ""
    | _ -> value.ToString()
```

Now the aformentioned `foo.Format` call will not compile.

The same goes with all the other basic types (`int`, `float`, etc.).